# Is it possible to give any recommendations about importing image in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I have a problem with importing images in Netlolgo version 6.1.1 while having added fetch, import-A, and bitmap extensions.

To specify, the error that is given:

```
import-pcolors: C:\Users\user\Desktop\...image.bmp (The system cannot find the file specified)
error while observer running IMPORT-PCOLORS
  called by procedure SETUP
  called by Button 'setup'
```

please I  would appreciate any recommendations

thank you in advance

Comment: Can you share the full code you are using to try the import?

Comment: That error is saying it can't find the file. As a first attempt to debug, I'd be putting everything in the same folder and removing all spaces in file names.

Comment: Thanx both for responding. JenB, actually worked somehow as you said. Why this goes for some and for all projects tho?

Comment: @Br.Elina we don't know what exact path you gave, and we don't know what directories and files exist on your computer and how they are named and arranged, so it's impossible to answer, other than to say that if NetLogo says the path you provided doesn't actually exist, it's a safe bet it's correct. NetLogo can't know what you _meant_